# gmail calendar is not working on host (asp.net mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, gmail, google-calendar-api

I'using gmail calendar api to get my events. my codes is working local but when I publish my asp.net mvc project my project is not working at host.

when I write  http://localhost/deneme/index at browser then  I see login page of gmail. but after publish I cannot see gmail login page.

```cs
public ActionResult index()
{
    try
    {
        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets
            {
                        ClientId = "993546 s.googleusercontent.com",
                        ClientSecret = "z2FJkeSr 2exhwGtrD0"
            },                    
            new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None).Result;

        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "gmailtakvimuygulamasi",
        });

        Events request = null;
        ListRequest lr = service.Events.List("foralongtimes@gmail.com");
        request = lr.Execute();

        Event evnt = request.Items.FirstOrDefault();
        ViewBag.deneme = evnt.Start.ToString() + " " + evnt.Description;

        TempData["UyariMesaji"] = evnt.Start.ToString() + " " + evnt.Description;

        return View();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.deneme = ex.Message;
        throw;
    }
}
```

when I run my project in my local computer, I can see login page of gmail. but after publish  I cannot see gmail login page at host.therefor I can not get my events of gmail calender...